# Creating subfileds of nested array in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, java-8, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
POST feeds/_doc
{
  
  "feed_id": "3",
  "title": "jose ",
  "body": "This is Jose allen",
  "comment": [
    {
      "c_id": "13",
      "feed_id": "2",
      "c_text": "hey"
    },
    {
      "c_id": "13",
      "feed_id": "3",
      "c_text": "  here"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is the mapping

```
PUT feeds
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "comment":{
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create feed class with mentioned feilds the comment field has nested type fields with sub fileds of c_text,c_id .how can i create it

```
@Document(indexName = "feeds")
public class Feed {
    @Id
    private String feed_id;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "title")
    private String title;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "body")
    private String body;
    
    @Field(type= FieldType.Nested , name="comment")
     private String[] comment;

}
```

how to intialize subfields of comment field as i am using elasticsearch 7.17.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Comment` class like this:

```
public class Comment {

    @JsonProperty("c_id")
    private String cId;

    @JsonProperty("feed_id")
    private String feedId;

    @JsonProperty("c_text")
    private String cText;

    // Getters, setters, ...
}
```

and instead of using `private String[] comment`, you should use:

```
@Field(type= FieldType.Nested , name="comment")
private List<Comment> comment;
```

Comment: after using  @Field(type= FieldType.Nested , name="comment")
private List<Comment> comment;    i have to create neew class comment ?

Comment: ..yes @aliabbasi

Comment: ok correct me if i am wrong if i want to use (c_text) some where i have to use (Comment.c_text) ?

Comment: @aliabbasi You have to use `Feed feed = new Feed(); feed.getComment().get(0).getCText();` note that the comment attribute is a list so to extract the cText you need to retrieve it from one element by using element index

Comment: i have to use this querry and pass the(c_text)how can i use this into my querry Query matchQuery = MatchQuery.of(mq -> mq.field("comment.c_text").query("hey"))._toQuery();

Comment: @Ali this should be in another question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250697/discussion-between-ali-and-ycf-l).